# Pushing a view onto the Navigation Stack from a view inside a container view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

**Current Design**

I currently have a view controller on my storyboard that has an embedded tab controller and an embedded navigation control. This view control also has a container view that shows a view dependent upon the value selected in the segmented control located in the navigation bar.

[image: Storyboard View]

**Loading Views for the Container View**

The views for the container view are XIB files (not storyboard based) and are loaded programmatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // First Controller
    self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    // Second Controller
    self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    // Add the controllers to an Array
    self.controllers = @[self.firstViewController, self.secondViewController];

    // Set the container to show the first view controller on load
    [self displayContentController:[self.controllers firstObject]];
}

- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Set current controller
    self.currentController = content;
}
```

**The Problem I Face**

The problem I have is that one of the views for the container view is a collection view that contains photos and I need to be able to push a view containing an image in large size when they select one of the cells.

How do I go about pushing a view onto the navigation controller in a view that is inside the container view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your containerViewController embedded inside a navigationController ?

If so, you can simply call `self.navigationController` from within `firstViewController` or `secondViewController`

It will traverse the `parentViewController` chain upwards until it reaches a `UINavigationController` (or subclass) - then you would call -`pushViewController:animated:` on that navigationController.

In fact for your own containerController, you should also provide a category for `UIViewController` which adds a simple getter for your container:

```
@interface UIViewController (YourContainer)

    - (YourContainer *)yourContainer;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (YourContainer)

- (YourContainer *)yourContainer
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[YourContainer class]]) {
        return (YourContainer *)self;
    }    

    UIViewController *parent = self.parentViewController;

    while (! [parent isKindOfClass:[YourContainer class]] && parent != nil) {
        parent = parent.parentViewController;
    }

    return (YourContainer *)parent;
}

@end
```

This will give you the same behavior for childViewControllers as `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` provide. In fact, if you have a look at the headers for these classes, you'll see that they also provide this functionality through a category on `UIViewController` -- so from now on, every childViewController can call `self.yourContainer` to get a reference to your custom container, or nil, if it is not contained in one.

Comment: calling [self.navigationController pushViewController:singleImageController animated:YES] inside one of the container view views worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious though, would it be advantageous to set up a category for the UIViewController in this case? I understand categories a bit but I've only been programming in Objective C for 5 weeks.

Comment: Well, you don't HAVE to create a category. But i highly recommend you always provide this functionality for childs of your custom container. Imagine the following: child A receives an action from the user which requires you to show child B - of course, the logic for showing child B is in your container class, but how can you get a reference to your container from child A to perform the action to show child B ? - the UIViewcontroller category is the best approach in this case - i hope the example is not too confusion ;)

Comment: Just remember to import "UIViewController+YourContainer.h" wherever you need it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a navigation controller before your `history feedback item`,

To add Navigation controller,

1.Select your `history feedback item` controller,

2.From `Editor > Embed In > NavigationController like below Image:

[image]

Now in Your cell/photo selection method use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourUIViewController  animated:YES];
```